# how to get field name types from a sql database

Tags: mysql

To get field names one would use the command:

```
select column_name from information_schema.columns where table_name='person';
```

My question is how would one also get the field types in a similar list?

Comment: Probably there's no need for digging up this old thread but just for future sakes, one could always say `SELECT * FROM infromation_schema.columns WHERE table_name = 'person'` and see for himself what possible columns he could get.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
SELECT
    column_name,
    column_type    # or data_type 
FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE table_name='person';
```

[Schema Info](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/columns-table.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
select column_name,
       column_type 
  from information_schema.columns 
 where table_name='person';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    column_name,
    data_type
FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE table_name='person';
```

Answer (score 0):

If we want both column_name & column_type or Data Type:
select column_name,
       column_type 
  from information_schema.columns 
 where table_name='personal_info';

If we want only column_name:

select column_name
  from information_schema.columns 
 where table_name='personal_info';

If we want only column_type:
select column_type 
  from information_schema.columns 
 where table_name='personal_info';

Answer (score 0):

al shema

> SELECT table_name, column_name ,column_type FROM information_schema.columns   WHERE table_schema = 'shema name'